# How to speed up mysql query against a 204 million record table

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

For some reason my server has been finicky lately and for the life of me I can't figure out why. I monitor the memory usage by running

```
shell# watch -n 5 free -m
```

without running any activities memory used is anywhere from 4-5 GB. Once I run a query it starts increasing all the way up to 35 GB. For example, see output below

```
Every 5.0s: free -m                                     Fri Mar 13 10:17:28 2015

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         36196      34429       1767          0        124       3172
-/+ buffers/cache:      31132       5064
Swap:        24563          0      24563
```

the query I am running is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1),c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12
FROM db1.tb1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db2.tb2 WHERE db2.tb2.c1 = db1.tb1.c1)
and c6='X' and c9 <='y' and c10>= 'Z' and c12>='N'
GROUP BY c1
LIMIT 5000
```

All columns on both tables are indexed. Normally this query only takes me a couple of minutes. But last couple days, it has been taking 4+ hours

The `db1.t1` has 360 columns and 204 million records. So it is quite large
It uses the InnoDB engine

Ubuntu  v. 12.04

MySQL 5.5

I have 36 GB RAM installed

4 core Intel Xeon processor 2.93 GHz with hyper threading enabled.

Below is my my.cnf file (im only going to post the un-commented portions of the file)

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql    
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr    
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 50.253.189.57
key_buffer      = 5G
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 50
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 500
table_cache            = 3200
thread_concurrency     = 10
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1G
join_buffer_size = 500M
sort_buffer_size = 5G
query_cache_limit   = 0
query_cache_size        = 0
open-files-limit = 65535
tmp_table_size = 3G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
table_definition_cache = 1024
table_open_cache = 2048
thread_cache_size = 50
max_connect_errors = 1000000
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16
```

Comment: Why is there a parenthesis around `c1` in:  `SELECT DISTINCT (c1) ...`? Do you know it's redundant? `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: More important, do you know that selecting `c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12` which are not included in the `GROUP BY` (only `c1` is) means that you may get indeterminate results for all columns (except `c1`)?

Comment: No i didnt know it was redundant, thanks for the heads up. and yes i know about the GROUP BY because i only want unique records for c1, and when i dont put that as the group by i then have to go dedupe c1 in excel anyway.

Comment: And since you have `GROUP BY c1`, the `DISTINCT` is redundant as well. You can remove it, too. Each row will have a distinct c1 value, so no need to use distinct. So, you either keep `GROUP BY c1` and remove `DISTINCT` (which means you don't mind indeterminate results). Or you remove the `GROUP BY` and keep the `DISTINCT` (which will give you determinate results but a different query than you have now - possibly more than 1 row with same `c1`).

Comment: okay that is very helpful, thank you for that input

Answer (score 1):

> All columns on both tables are indexed.

Enough said.  That is *not* the right way to go about indexing.

> WHERE db2.tb2.c1 = db1.tb1.c1

db2.tb2 needs `INDEX(c1)` -- Keep in mind that a PRIMARY KEY is a UNIQUE key is an INDEX, so do not redundantly add INDEX if you already have `PRIMARY KEY(c1)`.

> and c6='X' and c9 <='y' and c10>= 'Z' and c12>='N'

Needs a *compound* index; recommending adding these three, since there are no clues of which would be best:

```
INDEX(c6, c9)
INDEX(c6, c10)
INDEX(c6, c12)
```

At the same time, remove `INDEX(c6)` because it is now redundant.  For further discussion, [Cookbook on making an INDEX, given a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

> tmp_table_size = 3G
>   max_heap_table_size = 1G

Very dangerous.  Are you swapping?  Swapping is *much* worse on performance than lowering some of the settings.  Each SELECT that needs a tmp table will allocate 1GB; if you have lots of such queries running at the same time, you will rapidly chew up RAM.  Lower both of those to their defaults.

> key_buffer = 5G

That is for *MyISAM indexes*.  If you are not using MyISAM, set it to 20M.  InnoDB is the preferred engine; 26G (out of 36GB) is reasonable if all of your tables are InnoDB.

There may be more suggestions; see how far you get with these.

**Edit**

> DISTINCT(c1),c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12

May not mean what you think -- DISTINCT is not a function, and the parens are irrelevant.  That de-dups the entire set of 12 expressions.  Also, it is probably irrelevant, unless you actually have duplicate rows.

Is `c1` your PRIMARY KEY?  Hence UNIQUE?  So the GROUP BY is also irrelevant.  Removing it may help speed.

Comment: Another possibility for the index would be `(c6,c1)` (which can used for group by) and - independent - including all the columns in the index, eg.: `(c6, c1, c9, c10, c12)` .

Comment: Including all 12 columns in the SELECT would be a "covering index"; stopping at the 5 in the index in unlikely to help at all.

Comment: OKay thanks for all of the feedback. first thing should i be keeping the exists or not exists statement?

Comment: c1 isnt primary key, but i need only that collumn to be unique records.

Comment: And no i am not swapping which i was not sure if that was odd or not.

Comment: Another comment to lowering tmp table size as you suggested, i was on the phone with percona earlier today and they had made a comment about it possibly being that their are too many tmp disks created to possibly raise that. I use phpmyadmin and took a look at the statuses and the variable "created_tmp_disk_tables" seems to be extremely high. --154

Comment: "high" depends on Uptime.  Divide Created_tmp_disk_tables / Uptime .  1 per second is probably not "terrible"; a few per minute is not "bad".  Zero is hard to attain.  If raising tmp_table_size to the point where it swaps, that is _much_ worse than having a few more disk tmp tables.  RAM/1000 is too big for tmp_table_size, in my opinion.  I'll be happy to argue with Percona.

Comment: The GROUP BY is still a problem.  It should include all non-aggregate values in the SELECT.  If not, you could get random information for c2..c12.  Why are you doing the GROUP BY?

Comment: For the GROUP BY i essentially want only unique phone numbers, so lets same i have 3 people in a house all with different names but the same phone number, i dont want all 3 to be exported only 1 of the records with the unique phone number.